# Using But keyword in BDD throws Step not implemented exception while running scenario in Quantum framework

Tags: selenium, cucumber, bdd, qaf, perfecto

I am trying to run a BDD scenario in Quantum framework. While execution, the step with But keyword fails with error "Step not yet implemented".

```
Auto-generated code snippet by QMetry Automation Framework.
TODO: remove NotYetImplementedException and call test steps
    throw new NotYetImplementedException();
```

I do not see issue with any other BDD keywords. Only the steps starting with "But" keyword fail with the above exception. Is there anything that I am missing?

Please find the scenario we are using

```
Scenario: Validate help me log in link
Given user have the "XXX" app in mobile
But user open the app by the name "XXX"
```

Step  implementation:

```
import cucumber.api.java.en.But;
...
    @But("^user open the app by the name \"([^\"]*)\"$")
    public void user_open_the_app_by_the_name(String arg1) throws Throwable {
        try {
            AppiumUtils.stopApp(arg1);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        } 
    }
```

Comment: Is it working with `And` instead of `But`? Can you provide your bed step call, step definition and autogenerated code snnipet?

Comment: Have updated  the scenario and code for your reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QAF uses following BDD Keywords :

- Given
- When
- Then
- And
- Using
- Having
- With

As `But` is not inbuilt keyword it may give you error. It doesn't mean that you can't use `But` as keyword! There is a feature to support any custom keyword(s) by defining [synonyms](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/BDD_Keywords_Synonyms.html).

You can try add following property in `application.properties` file:

```
And=But;And
```

This will allow you to use `But` as keyword and should resolve your issue.